# Select columns with nonzero values that share index in pandas with no loops

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, pandas-groupby

Does anyone know how to split pandas dataframe into one with non-interfering with respect to index columns, i.e. convert this dataframe

```
    col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     0     0     0
1     2     0     0     0
2     3     1     0     0
3     4     2     1     0
4     0     3     2     0
5     0     4     3     0
6     0     5     4     0
7     0     0     5     1
8     0     0     6     2
9     0     0     0     3
```

to the following:

```
      new_col1  new_col2  new_col3  new_col4  new_col5  new_col6
0         1         0         0         0         0         0
1         2         0         0         0         0         0
2         0         4         0         0         0         0
3         0         0         7         0         0         0
4         0         0         0         5         0         0
5         0         0         0         7         0         0
6         0         0         0         9         0         0
7         0         0         0         0         6         0
8         0         0         0         0         8         0
9         0         0         0         0         0         3
```

in pandas without any `for` loops. The idea is to combine the values of all the columns that share an index to a new column, leaving no columns with index shared.

Comment: Which columns the sums end up is inconsistent.  For example: why does `7` end up in `df.loc[3, 'new_col3']` while `5` ends up in `df.loc[4, 'new_col4']`?

Comment: because 7 = 4+2+1 and 5 = 3+2 -- sums of all the elements in this row.

Comment: Yes, but why did one go into a new column and the other did not?

Comment: Each column in the final matrix stands for each non-overlaping region. That's why some columns contain more than one value.

Comment: These are the sorts of details that are important to communicate well.  I'm struggling to find the relationship.  On the other hand, you understand the relationship but are not helping us to "get it".  That is your responsibility as a question asker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit rewritten:

```
(df.sum(1).to_frame()
  .set_index(df.groupby((df.ne(0) * df.columns).sum(1)).cumcount().eq(0).cumsum(),
              append=True)[0]
  .unstack(fill_value=0).add_prefix('new_col'))
```

Output:

```
   new_col1  new_col2  new_col3  new_col4  new_col5  new_col6
0         1         0         0         0         0         0
1         2         0         0         0         0         0
2         0         4         0         0         0         0
3         0         0         7         0         0         0
4         0         0         0         5         0         0
5         0         0         0         7         0         0
6         0         0         0         9         0         0
7         0         0         0         0         6         0
8         0         0         0         0         8         0
9         0         0         0         0         0         3
```

One way you can do this:

```
s = df.groupby(df.ne(0)\
     .apply(lambda x: ','.join(df.columns[x].tolist()), axis=1))\
     .cumcount().eq(0).cumsum()

df_out = df.sum(1).to_frame().set_index(s, append=True)[0]\
  .unstack(fill_value=0).add_prefix('new_col')

df_out
```

Output:

```
   new_col1  new_col2  new_col3  new_col4  new_col5  new_col6
0         1         0         0         0         0         0
1         2         0         0         0         0         0
2         0         4         0         0         0         0
3         0         0         7         0         0         0
4         0         0         0         5         0         0
5         0         0         0         7         0         0
6         0         0         0         9         0         0
7         0         0         0         0         6         0
8         0         0         0         0         8         0
9         0         0         0         0         0         3
```

Psuedo Logic:

Find a list of all columns for non-zero values for each row.  Group rows, by this list and create an incrementing value using cumcount with cumsum.  Add this incrementing value to your index with append and unstack to create columns.

Comment: It was super helpful! Thanks! And I shall learn groupby better.